# Find the Pattern - "The Weird Pattern"

Tags: pattern, number-sequence

This pattern has fooled many people in the past... Even I was fooled. But I have met a friend of mine that is not fooled. Now, I am hoping to find more. This is the pattern:

> 67 376 998 762 45 938 788 113 123 83 624
>
> Find the next number and give the reason.

P.S.: There is more than one answer. Any acceptable reason will be accepted. So give the reason.

---

Challenge: Find the next 15 numbers.

Comment: I've added the `number-sequence` tag as this appears to be _"A puzzle that asks for finding the hidden pattern in a given number sequence."_ If it isn't so, please do remove the tag.

Comment: Puzzles with no "right" answer are generally discouraged; you should have some objective criteria, even if arbitrary, for determining the "best" or most "right" answer, so that we're not just assembling a collection of valid solutions. Questions where "there is more than one answer" for which "any acceptable reason will be accepted" are, pretty much by definition, **Too Broad** and very likely to be closed as such.